# Selecting from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables namely States, Package_Details. Below are the details of the table.

States

- state_id
- state_name

Package_Details

- id
- sender_state        //Stores state with state ID
- receiver_state      //Stores state with state ID

Now I am having problems constructing a SQL query that will select and display the records in the Package_Details replacing the sender_state and receiver_state with the corresponding state_name in States table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a join. Example:

```
SELECT p.id, s1.state_name AS sender, s2.state_name AS receiver
  FROM 
       package_details p
  JOIN states s1 ON (p.sender_state = s1.state_id)
  JOIN states s2 ON (p.receiver_state = s2.state_id)
```

Note how you can uses `states` twice in the query by assigning it an alias (`states s1`) and using the aliases to refer to the table.

If you need to do this join often, you may wish to create a view.

MySQL's documentation on joins is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html. The documentation on creating views is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html.

Comment: I'm sure you know about joins. What you need to learn is 'aliasing' tables in queries. This allows you to use a table more than once in a query.

Comment: @Salman A: I assume that's directed at @War Coder, as its in example? I'll add a note in my answer about it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read up on SQL JOINs:

http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html